# Should an entity be written to ensure auto allocated ids are not reused?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have User entity group and Transaction entity under that. I autoallocate ids for the transactions. I want to create unique key for integration with the payment service. Since the transaction is not a root entity, the autoallocated ids are not guaranteed to be unique and hence I can't use them as the unique keys. What I am currently doing following the suggestion at

[Google Cloud Datastore unique autogenerated ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407626/google-cloud-datastore-unique-autogenerated-ids)

is to have a dummy root entity and allocate ids for it and store that id with the transaction entity as a separate field. However, since it is dummy, I am currently not writing the dummy entity itself to the datastore.

I have read other posts

[When using allocateIds(), how long do unused IDs remain allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768129/when-using-allocateids-how-long-do-unused-ids-remain-allocated)

and

[Are deleted entity IDs once again available to App Engine if auto-generated for an Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597750/are-deleted-entity-ids-once-again-available-to-app-engine-if-auto-generated-for)

but am still not sure. Do I have to insert this dummy entity with just the key? If not, how are all the allocated ids for this dummy entity tracked and what happens to the corresponding storage usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entity key ID, together with the kind and ancestor (and maybe namespace as well) define a unique entity key, which is **meaningful** even if the entity doesn't actually exist: it's possible to have child entities in an entity group ancestry attached to an ancestor which doesn't exist. From [Ancestor paths](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths) (emphasis mine):

> When you create an entity, you can optionally designate another entity
>   as its parent; the new entity is a child of the parent entity (note
>   that unlike in a file system, **the parent entity need not actually
>   exist**).

So the fact that your dummy entities actually exist or not should not matter: their key IDs pre-allocated using `allocateIds()` should never expire. From [Assigning identifiers](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers):

> Datastore mode's automatic ID generator will keep track of IDs that
>   have been allocated with these methods and will avoid reusing them for
>   another entity, so you can safely use such IDs without conflict. You
>   can not manually choose which values are returned by the
>   `allocateIds()` method. The values returned by `allocateIds()` are
>   assigned by Datastore mode.

Personal considerations supporting this opinion:

- the datastore has no limit of the number of entities of the same kind, ancestor and namespace, so it should support a virtually unlimited number of unique IDs. IMHO this means that there should be no need to even consider re-using them. Which is probably why there is no mention about any deadline or expiry time for allocated IDs.
- if IDs for deleted entities would ever be reused it would raise a significant problem for restoring datastore entities from backups - potentially overwriting newer entities with re-used IDs with the entities that used the same IDs previously